# WPF MVVM content of Listbox of an Entity depends on another Listbox of an Entity

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, listbox

Business Rule:
A placement can be filled by an opening where a Candidate that matches the opening can be assign.
An Opening required One Qualification.
A Candidate can have many Qualification and a Qualification may be acquired by many Candidate so Associative Certificate was made to avoid many-to-many Relationship.

Problem:
The Main Window shows Qualification, Candidate and Placement. In order to add placement i click the Add Placement Window which has a DataContext of PlacementModel and a New Window Appears which has 2 Listbox and a Button for Finalizing the Add, user must select an Opening in a listbox and a list of Candidates where there qualification matches appear in another listbox. The binding path for the 2 listbox are Openings and Certificates, respectively.
I want to make the Certificate Listbox updates its list whenever i click an Opening.

Entities are Candidate, Qualification, Placement, Certificate and Opening.

How can I implement this?

ListBoxes Binding Path:

LstOpenings(ItemsSource = Openings, SelectedItem= SelectedOpening)

LstCertificates(ItemsSource = Certificates, SelectedItem = SelectedCertificate)

PlacementModel:

```
#region Public Interface
public ObservableCollection<OpeningModel> Openings { get; private set; }
public ObservableCollection<CertificateModel> Certificates { get; private set; }
public OpeningModel SelectedOpening { get { return _selectedOpening; } set { _selectedOpening = value; } }

public CertificateModel SelectedCertificate
{
    get { return _selectedCertificate; }
    set
    { _selectedCertificate = value;
    }
}

#endregion

#region Private Helper
private void GetOpenings()
{`enter code here`

    var all = _context.Openings.OrderBy(cust => cust.OpeningDescription).ToList()
        .Select(
            opening =>
                new OpeningModel(opening, _context, _openingRepository, _companyRepository,
                    _qualificationRepository,_certificateRepository));
    Openings = new ObservableCollection<OpeningModel>(all);
    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Openings);
    view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription( "OpeningDescription",ListSortDirection.Ascending));

}


private void GetCertificates()
{

    if (_selectedOpening == null)
    {
        Certificates = new ObservableCollection<CertificateModel>();

    }
    else
    {
        var all =_certificateRepository.GetCertificates().Where(c => c.QualificationCode == _selectedOpening.QualificationCode)
                        .OrderBy(c => c.Qualification.QualificationDescription)
                        .ToList().Select(c=>new CertificateModel(c,_context,_certificateRepository,_candidateRepository,_qualificationRepository));
        Certificates = new ObservableCollection<CertificateModel>(all);
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Certificates);
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("QualificationDescription", ListSortDirection.Descending));
    }
} 
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new property of type `OpeningModel` named `Opening` and data bind that to the `ListBox.SelectedItem` property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Openings}" SelectedItem="{Binding Opening}" ... />
```

Now all you need to do is update the `Certificates` collection whenever the `Opening` value is changed. You can do that from the `Opening` property setter:

```
public OpeningModel Opening
{
    get { return opening; }
    set
    {
        opening = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Opening");
        UpdateCertificates();
    }
}
```

I'll leave it up to you to complete the `UpdateCertificates` method, as I'm sure you know how to do that.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what I should put inside UpdateCertificates().
I tried  using the code inside my GetCertificates() method but with the assumption that selected opening will never be null so if condition is no longer applicable. This method didn't work so I don't really know what to put in UpdateCertificates which will make The Listbox of Certificate filter out unqualified candidates each time I click an opening